# Concatenate Array with sheet names excel vba

Tags: arrays, loops, excel, concatenation, vba

Please see the question below the code.Thanks in advance

```
 Dim Acount As Long
Dim Bcount As Long
Dim Ccount As Long
Dim Dcount As Long
Dim Ecount As Long
Dim Fcount As Long
Dim Gcount As Long
Dim Hcount As Long
Dim Rcount() As Long
Dim Numrows As Long
Dim NamAry(1 To 7) As Variant
Dim SheetsVal(1 To 7) As Variant
Dim Pub(1 To 7) As Variant

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="N:\Desktop\Data.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
    Sheets("Academy").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$U").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks(Data2.xlsm).Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Acount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1


    Sheets("Cambridge").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$T").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks(Data2.xlsm).Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Bcount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1


    Sheets("Brantford").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Q").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks(Data2.xlsm).Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Ccount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

    Sheets("Sherwood").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Q").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks(Data2.xlsm).Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Dcount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

    Sheets("KMY").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Y").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks(Data2.xlsm).Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Ecount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

    Sheets("Ship").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AA").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks(Data2.xlsm).Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Fcount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

    Sheets("PFS").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$T").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks(Data2.xlsm).Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Gcount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

    Sheets("DUMP").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$T").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Workbooks(Data2.xlsm).Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Hcount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1


    'Sheets("Sheet9").Select
        'Range("A1").Select
        'NamAry = Array(Acount, Bcount, Ccount, Dcount, Ecount, Fcount)
   ' MsgBox NamAry()

NamAry(1) = Acount
NamAry(2) = Bcount
NamAry(3) = Ccount
NamAry(4) = Dcount
NamAry(5) = Ecount
NamAry(6) = Fcount
NamAry(7) = Gcount

SheetsVal(1) = "Academy"
SheetsVal(2) = "Cambridge"
SheetsVal(3) = "Brantford"
SheetsVal(4) = "Sherwood"
SheetsVal(5) = "KMY"
SheetsVal(6) = "Ship"
SheetsVal(7) = "PFS"


For INX = LBound(NamAry) To UBound(NamAry)
  Debug.Print NamAry(INX)
Next

For INX = 1 To 7
    If NamAry(INX) > 0 Then
        Pub(INX) = SheetsVal(INX)
    End If
Next

For INX = LBound(Pub) To UBound(Pub)
  Debug.Print Pub(INX)
Next
```

So I get the Following Output
 13

0

0

0

4

12

0

1.Academy

2.

3.

4.KMY

5.

6.Ship

7.

How Can i get an array, lets say Pub in this case without the blanks and this being the output format=
pub = Array("Academy", "KMY", "Ship")
I need to use this in a set of code but cant get my head around to figure this out.Basically i am looking for a concatenated array with sheet names with rows>0 based on the autofilter result

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you just want an array of the sheet names where there are any records that meet the filter condition in Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5")?

Comment: yes pretty much. I want to ultimately use this later and publish 1 document

Comment: See my answer below then. This achieves the same result much more simply.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this approach be better?

```
Sub CountNonZeroFilters()

Dim cl As Range
Dim output() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

ReDim output(0 To 0)

'loop over all worksheets in book
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case sht.Name

        'list all the sheets you want to check here
        Case "Academy", "Cambridge", "Brantford"

               'loop over cells in filter column
               For Each cl In sht.Range(sht.Range("A2"), sht.Range("A2").Offset(sht.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 0))

                    'if cell meets filter criteria add sheet name to array and go to next sheet
                    If cl.Value = Sheets("4.1").Range("J5").Value Then

                        ReDim Preserve output(0 To UBound(output) + 1)
                        output(i) = sht.Name
                        i = i + 1
                        GoTo nextSht

                    End If

                Next cl

        Case Else

            'do nothing

    End Select

nextSht:

Next sht


'test array

For i = 0 To UBound(output)

    Debug.Print output(i)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a type mismatch error at
 If cl.Value = Sheets("4.1").Range("J5") Then

Comment: Try 'If cl.Value = Sheets("4.1").Range("J5").Value' Then

Comment: still getting the same error. The value from Sheets("4.1").Range("J5") would be a string i believe

Comment: cl.Value will return a string if the cells in column A on the sheet being tested conain strings, so we are just comparing these to the srting in Sheets("4.1").Range("J5") . I see no reason for this to cause a type mismatch error.

Comment: What is the value of cl.Value when the error is caused?

Comment: something of this order 32.02.02 oe 44.04.04. Why do you want it to select it to A2?. My search fields are in entire Column A.

Comment: It's doing the Range between A2 and the the bottom of the current region of A2 (i.e. the bottom of the column, assuming there are no blanks). You could replace 'sht.Range(sht.Range("A2"), sht.Range("A2").Offset(sht.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 0))' with any range that covers just the cells in the filter column you want to check.